# typecasting subclass variable to superclass in java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I was reading about typecasting of superclass variables into subclass and vice versa in Java. Please tell which of these are  valid?

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Animal a = c;

Animal a = new Animal();
Cat c = (Cat) a;

Animal a = new Cat();
Cat c = (Cat) a;

Cat c = new Cat();
Dog d = (Dog) c;
```

Animal is the super class with Cat and Dog sub classes.

Comment: Try it and see first.

Comment: why don't you compile them and see?

Comment: My guess is none of the casts are valid since `cat` and `dog` are not types of any kind.

Comment: My guess is you're wrong. Oops, it's not a guess. :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typing error they are Cat and Dog only

Answer (score 0):

```
Cat c = new Cat();
Animal a = c;

Animal a = new Cat();
Cat c = (Cat) a;
```

Comment: first one you have there is iffy, what if the constructor for cat set up some other stuff?

Comment: What if the cat ate the dog?

Comment: Cast it to a Tiger, maybe

Comment: Please check the second one again..if could explain why it is not correct

Comment: @user2538255 -- `Cat` is a more specific type than 'Animal` (presumably).  The second one isn't allowed because the `Animal` might *not* be a `Cat` and `c` can only ever hold `Cat` objects.  In a nutshell "All `Cat`s are `Animal`s but not all `Animal`s are `Cat`s"

Answer (score 0):

The third one is ok as `a` is a `cat`, the others are dangerous nonsense whether the compiler will allow them or not.

Comment: First one is OK too.  It's exactly the same idea as passing a variable to a method that expects the supertype, or adding an item to a a list of that item's supertype.  Sure it's a little goofy, but this seems like a contrived early homework assignment to me.

Comment: No it is isn't, if you passed cat as animal then you would only be calling methods defined in Animal. Any extra properties or methods in cat would not work as expected. Might as well have casted it to Cockroach.

Comment: They'd work just fine, if they were defined virtual (or non-final since we're in Java) or overridden.  If they were new methods or properties (So defined on Cat but not on Animal), they'd simply be inaccessible through the Animal variable.  This is the whole point of inheritance.  If Cat and Animal don't behave this way, it's a sure sign of bad design (violates Liskov substitution principle).

Comment: If, if.. You want to throw a should, a might and a maybe in there as well? Liskov substitition can only be applied when the compiler is allowed to do it's own typing. As soon as you use an explicit cast, all bets are off, that's why it's unsafe.

Comment: There is no explicit cast in the first example.  The compiler *is* doing the typing.  That's why it's OK.  You'd do the same thing by passing a `Cat` instance to a method expecting an `Animal`.  Examples 1 and 3 will work just fine.  Example 2 throws a `ClassCastException` and 4 won't compile.

Comment: In fact, the first line of example 3 is doing exactly the same thing as example 1:  Assigning an instance of `Cat` to a variable of type `Animal`

Comment: My apologies, just gone and re-read the question, Visit optician or lay off the drugs, or perhaps visit the optician so I can read the labels :(